# How to make a relationship of data from user pool to aws appsync model

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am new to amplify and appsync. I am trying to create a Post model that needs to have a relationship of the user who is creating the Post. The problem is my user is from cognito user pool.

What I want is the user from cognito I don't want to create new user table on dynamo db because cognito user pool already has its information I just want to get the user info that is creating that Post if I query the post.

How should I create a relationship of this?

I create amlify api like this

```
? Please select from one of the below mentioned services: GraphQL
? Choose the default authorization type for the API API key
? Enter a description for the API key: 
? After how many days from now the API key should expire (1-365): 7
? Do you want to configure advanced settings for the GraphQL API Yes, I want to make some additional changes.
? Configure additional auth types? Yes
? Choose the additional authorization types you want to configure for the API Amazon Cognito User Pool
Cognito UserPool configuration
Use a Cognito user pool configured as a part of this project.
? Configure conflict detection? No
```

Here is my current schema.grapql

```
type Post
    @model
    @versioned
    @aws_cognito_user_pools
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, queries: null }, { allow: public }]) {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String
    thumb: String
    slug: String!
    allow_comments: Boolean
    owner: String!
    post_type: String!
    add_to_nav: Boolean!
    version: Int!
    comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments")
}

type Comment
    @model
    @versioned
    @aws_cognito_user_pools
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, queries: null }]) {
    id: ID!
    content: String
    version: Int!
    post: Post @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
```

====================================================

## EDIT: Added result of data that I want

Here is the query that I want to perform

```
query ListPost {
  listPosts {
    items {
      title
      content
      owner{
          username
          id
          email
          first_name
          last_name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result that I want

```
{
  "data": {
    "listPosts": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "title 1"
          "content": "Test long text cotent"
          "owner": {
              "username": "user1"
              "id": "234234234"
              "email": "user1@test.com"
              "first_name": "John"
              "last_name": "Doe"
           }
        },
       {
          "title": "title 1"
          "content": "Test long text cotent"
          "owner": {
              "username": "user1"
              "id": "234234234"
              "email": "user1@test.com"
              "first_name": "John"
              "last_name": "Doe"
           }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find any documentation how to build something like this.

Comment: You can define user model and make a relation between the user and their posts(one to many)

Comment: Hello @Alex thank you for your response.

Do you mean like this 
`user: User @connection(name: "PostUser")`

Comment: Yes, and create a User model type. because `@connection` works on two models.but if you don't want to save user information, use `owner` for query. if it's not clear let me know to create a sample for you

Comment: I mean what I want is the user from cognito I don't want to create new user table on dynamo db because cognito user pool already has its information I just want to get the user info that is creating that Post if I query the post.

Comment: Ok, please attach `schema.graphql` file(inside amplify project) to your question, I will have a look

Comment: Hello @Alex I updated my question and added the full schema.graphql

Answer (score 0):

This should help for anyone else that is looking into doing this:

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/function/#usage

Scroll to:

Example: Get the logged in user from Amazon Cognito User Pools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33459728)